# Why does MySQL use a temporary table to drop a primary key?

Tags: mysql, sql

When using the command:

```
  ALTER TABLE my_table DROP PRIMARY KEY;
```

The state (when SHOW PROCESSLIST) appears as:

```
  copy to tmp table
```

Why would it need to use a tmp table to "drop" a primary key constraint?

Comment: "implementation detail" ;-) I would suspect the underlying data clustering changes -- e.g. it moves to a "heap" or otherwise re-clusters in that particular engine? (InnoDB? MyISAM?) Since it's a DDL operation -- and not a common one -- the "simplest way" is often the "best way", especially if it can reuse well-tested/verified code paths.

Answer (score 5):

Consider the case of a composite primary key. In this case, the DB engine has to create a new clustered index from a synthetic key, which will require moving rows around. (Keep in mind that rows are physically ordered on disk by the primary key.) Given the rarity of this situation, it's not really worth handling the special case where your primary key is already an integer.

Comment: Why not just create a synthetic key that matches the physical ordering already there.
96 less hours of table-recreation in my case.

Comment: @John How would you create such a key? How would you ensure that new items inserted appear in the correct order?